# All valid paths through graph with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to write a query which I suspect is quite simple but can't figure out the correct approach. I have organisational structure data in a Neo4J graph model. It consists of org_unit nodes (teams) and BELONGS_TO relationships. Each relationship has a start and end date to define the validity period of that relationship. I want to return all paths through the graph that are valid based on the dates. The paths can be of different lengths

This seems to require filtering relationships so a "higher" relationship fits within the validity period of the "lower" one (I'm going from bottom-upwards) The following goes some way towards achieving the result:

```
MATCH (a:Org_unit)-[r1:BELONGS_TO]->(b:Org_unit)
MATCH (c:Org_unit)-[r2:BELONGS_TO]->(d:Org_unit)
WHERE r1.endda_epoch > r2.begda_epoch 
AND r1.begda_epoch <= r2.endda_epoch 
AND b=c
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

However, I really want to return all complete paths. I thought I might be able to one of the use apoc.path.expand functions, but I think I would need to filter relationships based on attributes - and I can't see how to do this

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0):

### Example data

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (a:OrgUnit {name: 'A'})
    <-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2019-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(b1:OrgUnit {name: 'B1'}),
  (a)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2000-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(b2:OrgUnit {name: 'B2'}),
  (a)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2010-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(b3:OrgUnit {name: 'B3'}),
  (b2)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2010-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(c1:OrgUnit {name: 'C1'}),
  (b2)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2015-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(c2:OrgUnit {name: 'C2'}),
  (b2)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2018-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(c3:OrgUnit {name: 'C3'}),
  (b3)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2010-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(c4:OrgUnit {name: 'C4'}),
  (b3)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2020-01-01'), endDate: date('2021-12-31')}]-(c5:OrgUnit {name: 'C5'}),
  (c4)<-[:BELONGS_TO {beginDate: date('2019-01-01'), endDate: date('2019-12-31')}]-(d1:OrgUnit {name: 'D1'});
```

[image: initial situation]

### Solution

```
MATCH path = (root:OrgUnit {name: 'A'})<-[*..10]-(:OrgUnit)
WITH path WHERE 
  ALL(x IN relationships(path) WHERE x.beginDate <= $startDate) AND
  ALL(x IN relationships(path) WHERE x.endDate >= $endDate)
RETURN path;
```

**Used parameters:**

- `$startDate` = `date('2018-01-01')`
- `$endDate` = `date('2019-01-01')`

**Explanation:**

- line 1: match all possible paths from the root `OrgUnit` (CEO) to each `OrgUnit`, assuming the maximal organization depth is 10
- line 3: filter out those paths, where not all relationships fit to our `$startDate` parameter
- line 4: filter out those paths, where not all relationships fit to our `$endDate` parameter
- line 5: render the resulting paths

### Result

[image: resulting graph]

The `OrgUnit`s B1, C5 and D1 are omitted because they are valid from "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01" and "2019-01-01" only.

### Remark

Neo4j doesn't have a focus on searching and filtering of *relationship properties*. Modeling those attributes as node or property of a node is significantly more performant, especially for large graphs.

Comment: This is excellent - thank you. Is there a way of filtering for example the relationship from A2 to B2 based on the start and end date of the relationship from C1 to B2, and extending this to the complete graph - so that every "upper" relationship validity period overlaps with those "lower down"? This could result in multiple possible paths through - what I want to do eventually is transform the resulting paths into a table with columns for the levels - one row per valid paths, and include the "overall" start and end dates of the validity period for that path. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Can you please specify a result table with the concrete values you expect?